# FrameLayout with Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

I want to put the bottom navigation menu with my recyclerview at the bottom of the view. It is currently at the top and I need help sending it to the bottom.

This is how it look now:
[image]

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Oficinas Credenciadas"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
    />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/botton_nav_menu"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks works fine!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have made some changes and this is how it the items are positioned now.

[image]

> This is how the code looks now. If this helps you, an upvote would be appreciated. Thanks

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Oficinas Credenciadas"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_menu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView" />

    <!-- NOT SURE WHY YOU HAVE THE FRAMELAYOUT AND RECYCLERVIEW OCCUPYING THE SAME SPACE BUT IF YOU INTEND TO HIDE AND SHOW THEM AT DIFFERENT TIMES, I HAVE IMPROVED THEIR CONSTRAINTS -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_menu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/sample_menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

To bottom navigation item so code will be like that

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/botton_nav_menu"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Comment: thanks also work too